# Is there a way to get the number of buttons a joystick has?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, joystick

### Introduction

I am making a game in Unity that was designed for the player **to use all the letters on the keyboard**. The game shows a battle between two fighters, **prompts a key**, and the player must mash that key for his character to push the other.

The fun part is that, eventually, **the key to be pressed will change to another randomly**.

This game is about learning the keyboard for those who haven't learned it, or haven't got used to their flashing new keyboard just yet.

I want the game itself to be playable in more ways, and I made a port to Android that works by touching the sides of the screen, there are flashing button panels that change as the keys would.

### Issue

Now, the game has reached more that I want the game to be playable with controllers/**gamepads**/**joysticks**, but I'm afraid about two issues.

First and foremost: **How can I tell the number of button inputs a controller has?** I don't want my game to ask the player to press "JoystickButton**19**" when in their physical controller there are only 12 or so buttons.

---

I would add to the question "how do I know the actual name of the button itself?". In an example, how to know if the controller is a JoyCon. I noticed that in Fire Pro Wrestling World on Steam, the game recognizes the "SL" and "SR" buttons, so they got JoyCon specific layout there. If this question has to be answered in a new topic, I will make that.

This is my first question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.Gamepad.html 
They have mappings for the most common gamepads, and there is a separate joystick class as well. If you also go further down, DualShockGamepad, iOSGameController, SwitchProControllerHID, XInputController, you will see their default mappings as well as how to provide custom mappings for any compatible input device as well. Note that the InputDevice also has allControls property, that would list all the buttons and the directional pads.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks. So, the allControls property will be different for each gamepad, right?

Comment: Yes, all the gamepad classes derive from the InputDevice class, so whatever that is recognized as an InputDevice, should have a properly initialized allControls property. Let me know if this works for you so that I can come up with an answer.

Comment: Okay, so, I connected the Right JoyCon via Bluetooth and it was detected as a "Joystick".And I got to the array of controls via: 
`var joycon = Joystick.all[0];
string buttons = joycon.description.ToString()+"\n";
foreach(InputControl control in joycon.allControls)
 buttons+= control.name + " / ";
txtKey.text = buttons;` 

And it prints [this](https://i.ibb.co/Wk3VHtB/Inputs.png). 
I tried pressing every button at the same time on that JoyCon and it only uses a few of the presented inputs. Should I believe there are 16 digital buttons and only some are physical? Any suggestion? Thanks.